# Notepad++ how to replace on this case

Tags: replace, notepad++

I got about 32k lines on notepad++ and most of them are formatted as follows:

```
http://www. site</strong>.com</strong>/en/
```

They should be like this :

```
http://www. site.com
```

Note: TLD extensions are .com/.net/.us etc...

Comment: AFAIK Notepad++ supports regular expressions... I think you can do some research on how to use them to replace text. If you've tried something already, please post your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the text you wish to replace. In this case it will be in two parts. Firstly select `</strong>` , press **CTRL+F** (Windows) , Select "**Replace**" Tab, Enter the value to replace in the "**Replace with**" box. In this case nothing. And hit replace all.

Then repeat for `</strong>/en/`.

Simple.

Comment: Your answer is valid. However, I assume that the main issue is that there may be some more "garbage" in the strings... That's why I recommended some research on regular expressions, in case the OP has to deal with such problem